# unboundedness of a function implies the dense and compact inclusion on Hilbert spaces

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

Assume $f: N \to (0, \infty)$ (N, natural number) is a monotone increasing unbounded function. Define the Hilbert space $l^{2}_{f}$as the vector spaces of all real sequences $x=\{x_n\}_{n \in N}$ satisfying
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} f(n)x^{2}_n < \infty$$
with the inner product
$$
<x,y>_f=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}f(n)x_n y_n.
$$
For $k \in Z$, abbreviate $H_k=l^{2}_{f^k}$.

Show that the inclusion $H_{k+1} \to H_{k}$ is dense and compact.

First, I thought it's a basic, but I stuck here and can't show this for a long time.. How unboundedness implies density and compactness of the inclusion..  I would appreciate if you tell me some indication for proof or references. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\sum f(n)^{k} x_n^{2} \leq M \sum f(n)^{k+1} x_n^{2}$ $\cdots$ (1) where $M=\sup \{\frac 1 {f(n)}: n \geq 1\}$. So $\|T\| \leq M$ where $T$ is the given inclusion map. it is obvious that the range of $T$ includes all finitely non-zero sequences so the range is dense. To show that $T$ is compact define $T_N(x_n)=(x_1,x_2,...,x_N,0,0,,,)$ and verify using $\cdots$ (1) that $\|T_N-T\|\to 0$. Since $T_N$'s have finite rank it follows that $T$ is compact.

Comment: Thank you! but I also wonder how unboundedness of the monotone increasing function $f$ is connected to density and compactness.. Doesn't $M$ go to zero for such $f$?

Comment: Unboundedness of $f$ is needed even to show that $T$ is  a bounded operator. The norm of the operator is $M$ which is finite when $f$ is unbounded. @taminal

Comment: ok, I will try and check. Thank you so much!